# group laravel eloquent relationship items

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following models in my laravel app:

Consumption:

```
class Consumption extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ambulance() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ambulance::class);
    }

    public function consumption_item() {
        return $this->hasMany( ConsumptionItem::class );
    }

    public function consumption_items_grouped() {
        return $this->consumption_item()
            ->select('consumption_items.id', 'consumption_items.consumption_id',
            'consumption_items.item_id', 'consumption_items.item_stock_id', ConsumptionItem::raw('SUM(consumption_items.quantity) as quantity'))
            ->groupBy('consumption_items.item_stock_id');
    }
}
```

ConsumptionItem:

```
class ConsumptionItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function consumption() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Consumption::class );
    }
}
```

As you can notice, the relationship between them is one-to-many, a consumption can have many items. Also, a consumption has an ambulance_id

Now, I have the following case:
consumption 1 has ambulance_id = 5 and 10 items,
consumption 5 has ambulance_id = 5 and 6 items

If two or more consumptions have the same ambulance_id, then it should group into one and also group the items. is there any way to group the consumptions based on the ambulance_id? so instead of having 2 different positions (consumption 1 with 10 items and consumption 5 with 6 items), to have only one (consumption 1 with 16 items)

This is my current query:

```
$consumptions = Consumption::with('consumption_items_grouped',
'ambulance')
            ->whereIn('consumptions.ambulance_id', $subset)
            ->whereBetween('consumptions.document_date', [$old_from_date, $old_until_date])
            ->get();
```

A more clear example:
So the tables are consumptions and consumption_items. In the consumptions table I have:

```
id      ambulance_id

1       5

2       5
```

In the consumption_items table I have:

```
id      consumption_id      item_id

1       1                   7

2       1                   9

3       1                   4

4       2                   8
```

So instead of having two consumptions (consumption 1 with 3 items and consumption 2 with 1 item) I want only 1 consumption (consumption 1 with 4 items), since they both have the same ambulance_id

Comment: please add you data of database , and result of you want get

Comment: I left an example in the question. should I give a more clear example?

Comment: i think your defined relation not good, if i see your data and The intended result,I can help you better

Comment: I edited the question, can you check?

Comment: edited it again because the format was not good

Comment: What is the difference between the `id` and `item_id` columns on `consumption_items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk if i understand you well, but what i think that you want is a list of itemps per ambulance like this:

Ambulances

```
[
    {
        "id": 5, 
        "name": "Ambulance 5", 
        "consumption_items": [
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "consumption_id": 1,
                "item_id": 7,
                "item": {...}
            },
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "consumption_id": 1,
                "item_id": 9,
                "item": {...}
            },
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "consumption_id": 1,
                "item_id": 4,
                "item": {...}
            },
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "consumption_id": 2,
                "item_id": 8,
                "item": {...}
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

For this you should create your ambulance class and add a hasmanythrough relation.

```
class Ambulance extends Model {
    public function consumption_items()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ConsumptionItem::class, Consumption::class, 'ambulance_id', 'consumption_id');
    }
}
```

And then you can do this to get te previous result (if you only need the number of items per ambulance replace the with "with" with "withCount" method).

```
$ambulances = Ambulance::with('consumption_items', 'consumption_items.item')->get(); 
// You can manipulate this result to return the count of consumptiom_itemps on each ambulance on a foreach loop like $ambulance->consumption_items->count();
```

There is no way tou group by consumption as if, cause if you think, you would have to determine randomly the consumption id (1 or 2 in your case) to show as you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use relations , you query like bellow, please run this query... and say result is correct?

```
Consumption::query()
    ->selectRaw('
        consumption_items.id,
        consumption_items.consumption_id,
        consumption_items.item_id,
        consumption_items.item_stock_id,
        SUM(consumption_items.quantity) as quantity
    ')
    ->leftJoin('consumption_items', 'consumption_items.consumption_id', '=', 'consumptions.id')
    ->groupBy('consumption_items.consumption_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. I have to group the consumptions by the ambulance_id, and don't forget that I said the relationship is ONE-TO-MANY.. this query is one-to-one, because it returns only one consumption_item